# If H and K are normal subgroups of G and it is given that $G= H \times K$. Then how should I write a general element of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If H and K are normal subgroups of G and it is given that $G= H \times K$. Then how should I  write a general element of G. Is it (h,k) or hk? What if H and K are just the subgroups of G. I am a bit confused with the notations as we are not given it to be internal weak direct product.

Comment: It depends on the context.

Comment: By definition of a Cartesian product, elements of $H\times K$ are given by pairs $(h,k)$ with $h\in H$ and $k\in K$. If you are given $G=HK$, then you can write $g=hk$.